# Node server stops working after several times working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I have express setup to do server side rendering for a React project I'm working on, and it seems to just anomalously stop working after a certain amount of time following this progression:

1) Server goes up, returns pages successfully

2) I tweak the server files a bit, restart.

3) Server continues to work

4) Tweak more, restart

5) Server stops working, even if reverting back to the files used from step 1

6) Attached error continues to display on all future attempts until node_modules is deleted and all dependencies are reloaded

So, while I have a workaround for the moment, it's far from efficient to wipe the entire dependency set each time this comes up, and I have concerns whether this kind of behavior might surface when the app is deployed. What's going on here and how do I prevent it?

I've made sure node doesn't have leftover ghost processes running in background or anything, and the complete run log doesn't say much different than the error message is saying. Not sure of any other angles to consider here.

```
E:\JsProjects\ssrproj> npm run serve

> ssrproj@0.1.0 serve E:\JsProjects\ssrproj
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js

E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\convert-source-map\index.js:61
  return SafeBuffer.Buffer.from(json, 'utf8').toString('base64');
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
    at Converter.toBase64 (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\convert-source-map\index.js:61:28)
    at Converter.toComment (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\convert-source-map\index.js:65:21)
    at generateCode (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\file\generate.js:78:76)
    at runSync (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:50:51)
    at transformSync (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:43:38)
    at Object.transform (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:22:38)
    at compile (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\node.js:73:20)
    at compileHook (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\node.js:102:12)
    at Module._compile (E:\JsProjects\ssrproj\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:93:29)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ssrproj@0.1.0 serve: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ssrproj@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-13T15_17_36_311Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from the `convert-source-map`. Consider disabling it in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this error might be due to a race condition in the [safe-buffer](https://github.com/feross/safe-buffer) project, which appears to be a dependency of the convert-source-map project. Other people have had [a similar error when using safe-buffer](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static/issues/875).  Here are my suggestions. Try either:

1. Make sure you have the latest versions for convert-source-map and all related project
2. Avoid using convert-source-map in production.

Comment: Updating the parent projects using it seems to have worked (intermittent problems are hard to confirm quickly), thanks. Either way it sounds like you're right about the type of error. Probably not being reported as much if it's platform specific